# How to add button of social share in custom page magento 2

Tags: magento2, social-buttons

I have created a module that enable the client to apply for  job and iw ant to add in the page of detail of offer job 3 button :facebook, linkdin, twitter so how do do that without using extension any help please

Comment: https://github.com/ssatish4v/socialshare_qty_magento2

Answer (score 1):

> in your phtml file paste this code

```
 <div class="iconss">
                <?php $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";?>
                 <a href=<?php echo $block->getTwitterlink().$actual_link?>> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                 <a href=<?php echo $block->getFacebooklink().$actual_link?>> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                 <a href=<?php echo $block->getPinterestlink().$actual_link?>> <i class="fab fa-pinterest"></i></a>
  </div>
```

> in your block file create following functions

```
public function getFacebooklink(){
    return "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=";
}
public function getPinterestlink(){
    return "https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=";
}

public function getTwitterlink(){
    return "https://twitter.com/home?status=";
}
```

Comment: i think that it miss a script to share the detail of job